# return not displaying page data react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this page:

```
    import "../../../styles/services.css";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from "axios";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

import { setNavTabValue } from '../../../store/actions/navTab';
import UserNav from "../../../components/user/UserNav";
import Header from "../../../components/app/Header";


const AddMembershipPage = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  
    let ssoDetails = props.blue
    var myCnum = ssoDetails.uid;
    var empType = "part-time";
    var email = ssoDetails.preferredIdentity;
    var name = ssoDetails.preferredFirstName + " " + ssoDetails.preferredLastName;

    this.state = {
        cnum: myCnum,
        empType: empType,
        email: email,
        name: name,
        phone: "",
        siteList: "",
        status: ""
    };

  const handleInputChange = (e) =>
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });

const classes = useStyles();
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
  }));



  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <UserNav />
    <Header title="Membership" />
    <div className="App">
        <div id="form-main">
            <div id="form-div">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                    <p className="cnum">
                        <input
                            name="cnum"
                            type="hidden"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="cnum"
                            placeholder={this.state.cnum}
                            value={this.state.cnum}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            readOnly
                        />
                    </p>

                    {/* <p className="empType">
                        <input
                            name="empType"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="empType"
                            placeholder={this.state.empType}
                            value={this.state.empType}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            readOnly
                        />
                    </p> */}

                    <p className="email">
                        <input
                            name="email"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="email"
                            placeholder={this.state.email}
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            readOnly
                        />
                    </p>
                    <p className="name">
                        <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="name"
                            placeholder={this.state.name}
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            readOnly
                        />
                    </p>
                    <p className="phone">
                        <input
                            name="phone"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="phone"
                            placeholder="phone"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </p>
                    {/* <p className="building">
                        <input
                            name="building"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="building"
                            placeholder={this.state.building}
                            value={this.state.building}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                            readOnly
                        />
                    </p> */}
                    <p className="siteList">
                        <input
                            name="siteList"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="siteList"
                            placeholder="siteList"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </p> 
                    <p className="status">
                        <input
                            name="status"
                            type="text"
                            className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input"
                            id="status"
                            placeholder="status"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />
                    </p>

                    <div className="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" />
                        <div className="ease"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        siteTab: state.siteTab,
        blue: state.blue
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    setNavTabValue: (value) => dispatch(setNavTabValue(value))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddMembershipPage);
```

I am currently in the process of converting this page from `class based component` to  a `functional component`. however, I am having a significant amount of problems. Can someone help me convert this page? I have tried changing the `return (`, and now it is not displaying anything. I also changed the `handleInputChange`, and `handleInput` as well, and trying to fix up everything, but it is driving me nuts. can anyone help?

Comment: Doesn't seem much different from your previous question, since deleted. Anyways, the `connect` HOC still works the same, so if you are injecting `siteTab`, `blue`, and `setNavTabValue` as props, they still need to be accessed via the `props` object. `makeStyles` returns a `useStyles` hook, move it outside the component and call `useStyles` hook in the component. `ssoDetails` is a string, so there are no properties to access when initializing the `fields` state. `useInput` doesn't seem valid here, what are you trying to define?

Comment: @DrewReese yea I had to change the question and tame it a little bit to make it more for what I was looking for. So I did all that you mentioned above (thanks for your response btw), and it seems as though it fixed the errors I was getting, but it still isn't showing up on my screen. please see the updated code above.